# How to ignore selecting some options conditionally?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using `select2.js` plugin from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ for employee list drop-down with multiple selection.

```
<select id="empList" name="empList" multiple="multiple">
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<option value="1">emp 1</option>
<option value="2">emp 2</option>
<option value="3">emp 3</option>
```

my requirement is when user selects "**ALL**" then individual employees can't be electable. If user selects any employee then "ALL" Can Not be electable.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this code but it should look like this:

```
$('#empList').change(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.val() == undefined) { // Selected all option
       $.each(self.find('option'), function (res) {
           if (res.attr('value') != undefined) {
              res.prop('disabled', true);
           }
       })
    }
    else {
       $.each(self.find('option'), function (res) {
           if (res.attr('value') != undefined) {
              res.prop('disabled', false);
           }
       })
    }
})
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for you...
keep this in your script..,

```
$('#empList').click(function(){
   var Value = $(this).val();
   $("#empList option").each(function(){
      var Opt = $(this).val();
      if(Value == 'ALL'){
          if(Opt != Value){
              $("option[value="+Opt+"]").prop('disabled', true);
          } else {
              $("option[value="+Opt+"]").prop('disabled', false);
          }
      } else {
          if(Value == null) {
              $("option[value="+Opt+"]").prop('disabled', false);
          } else {
              $("option[value='ALL']").prop('disabled', true);
          }
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jaTPc/

Heres the modded html (added classes):

```
<select id="empList" name="empList" multiple="multiple">
<option value="ALL" class="all">ALL</option>
<option value="1" class="notall">emp 1</option>
<option value="2" class="notall">emp 2</option>
<option value="3" class="notall">emp 3</option>
</select>
```

And the jQuery

```
$("#empList").change(function() {
var optionAll = $(".all");
var optionOther = $(".notall");

this.value == "ALL" ?  optionOther.prop("disabled", true) : optionAll.prop("disabled", true);
});
```